# Fancybox suddenly stopped working

Tags: jquery, fancybox

in my website I use jquery and Fancybox plugin.
All was working good, but suddenly Fancybox stopped working.

When I click on images, they are loaded in the same window instead into a fancybox popup.

No errors are provided by javascript console, and I've not idea on how to fix it.
I've tried to run into javascript console:

```
$("a").fancybox();
```

and the result is the same, nothing works...
I've also tried to set jquery to version 1.8.2 but the problem remains.

Do you have some idea for fix it?

Edit: I've added to the jsfiddle the bootstrap.js and now if I run fancybox from javascript panel of jsfiddle it doesn't work.
If I remove it, it works again.

http://jsfiddle.net/pQwCh/

Comment: Please don't expect us to dissect your page.  Post the relevant code and construct a concise example in jsFiddle.

Comment: Try to break down your problem, I see that you use rel=lightbox, why is that? I don't see where you are using this <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").fancybox();
 });
</script>

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle.
I use data-rel="lightbox" and the code is into /assets/js/tekhy.js:
$("a[data-rel=lightbox]").fancybox();

Comment: Solved!

Was a bootstrap conflict, I've found the solution here:

https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/519

Comment: Please post your solution below as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Was a bootstrap conflict, I've found the solution here

https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/519